# How to calculate the needed Pa to penetrate a defined thickness material

Tags: kinematics

I am currently doing research for a video game I am developing, right now I am trying to figure out how to calculate how far a bullet will penetrate a plate of metal. I just need the bare bones physics equation. I've looked on wikipedia and I know how to calculate Newtons, Pascals, and mass of objects (those are easy). What's hard to find is some kind of physical property of elements (for example Osmium) that tells me how much pressure or force needed to penetrate a defined depth.

Comment: Could you just make up a simplified model if it's for a video game?

Comment: Short answer; Yes I could. Long answer: No, this project's aim is to be as scientifically accurate as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that night be sufficient is Newton's approximation to impact depth. It assumes the projectile is moving at a high velocity that is faster than the speed of sound in the target material. The depth is given by

$$D\approx\frac{\rho_P}{\rho_T}L$$

where $\rho_P$ and $\rho_T$ are the densities of the projectile and the target respectively, and $L$ is the length of the projectile.

Comment: Interesting, this could be useful until I can find a more precise equation. So if I had an osmium target and a Titanium projectile that's 1 cm long (0.01 Meters) that would mean D = 0.00199468791 = (4.506 g/cm3 / 22.59 g/cm3)0.01
Did I do that math correctly? It seems pretty accurate to me, considering how dense Osmium is compared to Titanium.
But this wouldn't take into account the thickness of the target.

Comment: @ReginaApis That looks fine. Yeah if your target is thinner than what you calculate then you will obviously just have a hole as deep as the thickness of the target

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help! I was googling different things for about 3 hours trying to figure this out! I was worried that the impact resistance would be increased by the thickness but your explanation was really easy to understand! I might do further research in the future on how speed affects the equation. I possibly reverse engineer to some degree.